# Godaddy Emails with redmine setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am trying to configure email notifications in Redmine . The email server I am using is of Godaddy.com ( it is email from cPanel and I access it using outlook using provided username password).

this is my configuration in configuration.yml file  http://prntscr.com/8qgp63

And this is what I got from godaddy http://prntscr.com/8qgpu3

I tried it for many days but really don't know where I am doing mistake.

Comment: You probably want to change your email password as in your screenshots, it is pretty well still readable.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed that by adding enable_starttls_auto: false

See below code

```
production:
 email_delivery:
 delivery_method: :smtp
 smtp_settings:

  address: mail.example.com
  enable_starttls_auto: false
  port: 25
  domain: example.com
  authentication: :login
  user_name: zeshan@example.com
  password: mypassword
```